# Guava breaks Spring boot start-up

Tags: spring-boot, guava

When following the instruction videos from LeanStacks, there is no problem adding caching using Guava. Doing the same for my own project will give me a org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException during startup.

I have tried to take away one piece at a time until I got it working, and builed it down to that it breaks when I add a @Cacheable annotation to my UserServiceBean class.

One suspicion of mine is that it happens beacause of the relations between my entity classes. Could this be the case? Otherwise what could cause this?

From the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My application is configured like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class Application {

    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run( Application.class, args );
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(){
        GuavaCacheManager cacheManager = new GuavaCacheManager( "EntWeb" );

        return( cacheManager );
    }
}
```

UserServiceBean.java

```
@Service
public class UserServiceBean implements UserService {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Override
    public User create(User user) {
        User ret = null;

        if( user.getId() == null ) {
            ret = userRepo.save( user );
        }

        return( ret );
    }

    @Override
    //This is what breaks the startup procedure!
    @Cacheable( value="EntWeb", key="#id")
    public User findOne(Long id) {
        User ret = userRepo.findOne( id );

        return( ret );
    }

... other service functions
```

User.java

```
@Entity(name="USERS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String email;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn( name="addressId" )
    private Address address;

... getters and setters
```

And the error message:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
refresh attempt:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired
dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
autowire field: private org.entweb.persistence.UserServiceBean
org.entweb.web.api.UserController.userService; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
qualifying bean of type [org.entweb.persistence.UserServiceBean]
found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Help appreciated

Edit 1: UserController.java

```
package org.entweb.web.api;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.entweb.model.User;
import org.entweb.persistence.UserServiceBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping( value = "/api/users" )
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceBean userService;

    @RequestMapping( 
            method = RequestMethod.POST, 
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<User> CreateUser( @RequestBody User user) {
        User persistedUser = userService.create(user);
        ResponseEntity<User> ret = null;

        if( null != persistedUser ) {
            ret = new ResponseEntity< User >(persistedUser, HttpStatus.OK );
        }
        else {
            ret = new ResponseEntity< User >( HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR );
        }

        return( ret );
    }

    @RequestMapping( value="/{userId}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
    public ResponseEntity< User > GetUser( @PathVariable( "userId" ) Long id) {
        User user = userService.findOne(id);
        ResponseEntity< User > ret = null;

        if( null != user ) {
            ret = new ResponseEntity< User >(user, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else {
            ret = new ResponseEntity< User >( HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND );
        }

        return( ret );
    }

    @RequestMapping( method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
    public ResponseEntity< Collection< User > > GetAllUsers() {
        Collection< User > users = userService.findAll();

        return( new ResponseEntity< Collection< User > >( users, HttpStatus.OK ) );
    }

    @RequestMapping( 
            value = "/{userId}",
            method = RequestMethod.PUT, 
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
    public ResponseEntity< User > UpdateUser( @RequestBody User user ) {
        ResponseEntity< User > ret = null;
        User updatedUser = userService.update(user);

        if( null == updatedUser ){
            ret = new ResponseEntity< User >( HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND );
        }
        else{
            ret = new ResponseEntity< User >( updatedUser, HttpStatus.OK );
        }

        return( ret );
    }

    @RequestMapping( value="/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity< User > DeleteUser( @PathVariable( "userId" ) Long id ){
        userService.delete(id);

        return( new ResponseEntity< User >( HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT ));
    }

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/search",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
            )
    public ResponseEntity< Collection< User > > UserSearch( @RequestParam( "type" ) String queryType, @RequestParam( "value" ) String value ){
        Collection< User > resp = null;
        ResponseEntity< Collection< User > > ret = null;

        switch( queryType ) {
        case "email": resp = userService.findByEmail( value ); break;
        default:
            resp = null;
        }

        if( resp.size() < 1 ){
            ret = new ResponseEntity<>( HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND );
        }
        else{
            ret = new ResponseEntity<>( resp, HttpStatus.OK );
        }

        return( ret );
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us your `UserController.class` or where you create `userController` bean?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, removing the relation to Address, does not cure the problem. Still get exception at startup.

Comment: Well in essence this tells that it can't inject the UserService into the controller. So I do assume the Service doesn't get created properly – either because it is also missing a dependency or because its not catched by Component Scanning. You stated the package of the Controller but on which packages do you have the Service and the @SpringBootApplicaiton?

Comment: The applicatiton is in package org.entweb; and the service is in package org.entweb.persistence;

Comment: And removing `@Cacheable˚ cures your issue?

Comment: If I remove that one Cacheable annotation, it starts like a charm

Comment: You have any further stack traces?

Comment: I remember running into a similar issue with the caching annotation related to auto-proxying. If I remember correctly we had to use the aspectj  compile time weaving - something about multiple proxies not being applied in the right order. Maybe this will help you find something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
@Autowired
private UserServiceBean userService;
```

to

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;
```

The reason is, that Spring creates a proxy for your class to implement the cache functionality. However, it uses by default the JDK proxy, when the bean implements an interface, and the JDK proxy then also implements the interface, but does not extend the bean class. So the bean is only of type `UserService` and not `UserServiceBean`. Also it is of no use to use the bean implementation type for fields, since this is what the interface is for. You want to code against the interface, not the implementation.

Comment: This is definitely the right way to go! +1 However, technically you could get away with using `@Autowired` on `UserServiceBean` (instead of `UserService`) if you enable caching using `@EnableCaching(proxyTargetClass=true)` and having `CGLIB` on the classpath

Comment: Yes! Thank you! That solved it! Very simple error that is hard to see.